# Single and whole group selection in tree table

Tags: tables, multi-selection, tree

We are using a tree table view in our product.
We also have a multiple selection in this view for purpose of bulk updating or drag and drop.
I would like the user to be able to single select the group only or to select the group with all of it sub items.

Actually I have 3 cases:

1. Only group selected without its sub items
2. Whole Group selected with all its sub items
3. Only one or more sub items selected without the parent group

Do you have an idea how to perform this selection and how to visualize it?

Answer (score 1):

I can only imagine to split the tree-select ("batch", case #2) from the individual-select (case #1 and #3). I would do it something like below. Having a button on top to toggle the selection modes and using indentation to communicate if the hierarchy-batch-select is "on" or "off".

[image: tree-select and individual-select mockup]

This shifts around the mental model of users of what the treeview does quite a lot . Therefore, I would test it with actual users to make sure they get it.

Comment: Thanks @Nash, we use tree table that I believe looks more like the individual select option. I've added a screenshoot above. not sure I can split to those two modes in our design. please check the new screenshoot and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Currently our view looks like the below, selected checkbox are aligned left.

By default, selecting a group will select only the group without it sub items.
We definitely need an option to select the whole group - with its sub items, can you advise how to add this option?

And how to visualize the 3 modes I mentioned previously.

[image]

Comment: It is better to edit your question in that case instead of posting an answer.

Comment: You could add an action column to the right of the status column with a context menu with "Select all children of current group".